# SpriteKit app using Swift begins to jitter on user interaction after 6 minutes

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have an app that is based on SpriteKit that uses swipe gesture recognition. After each swipe a new random image gets generated and ultimately removed. However, after 6 minutes the fluidity of my inputs begins to stop. If I leave the screen normal the animations are crips but if I touch the screen or try to interact with it, it lads the nodes. I don't even have a tap gesture recognizer. I am completely confused as to why my gestures get buggy after a while. Anyone have an ideas?

Comment: Maybe you have memory leaks, bugs, or just running it on the simulator that might get buggy even with the default code provided by Apple. Can you post some code? Did you run any debugging tools / check for memory leaks? I don't think the information you provided is enough for any of us to determine the problem.

Comment: It also sounds strangely familiar to the other user who just today reported a similar problem. Perhaps you too keep adding nodes but don't remove them? The sprite kit node count will only show the number of nodes being rendered, not the number in the hierarchy, which may lead beginning users to think that removal of nodes is automatic, which it isn't.

Comment: Posted some code. That's all within a function that gets called after every swipe.

Comment: sounds like a memory leak to me.  I see you add the image with the function addChild(), do you ever remove it?

Comment: Ah yes, I do. I declared this earlier.

    var removeImage = SKAction.removeFromParent()